# Why did Voldemort return to the house of his hated Muggle father?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

In *Goblet of Fire* Voldemort talks of how he detests his Muggle father.

> "You see that house upon the hillside, Potter? My father lived there. My mother, a witch who lived here in this village, fell in love with him. But he abandoned her when she told him what she was...he didn't like magic, my father..."
>   "He left her and returned to his Muggle parents before I was even born, Potter, and she died giving birth to me, leaving me to be raised in a Muggle orphanage...but I vowed to find him...I revenged myself upon him, that fool who gave me his name...*Tom Riddle*..."
>   <sub>*(Goblet of Fire, Chapter 33, The Death Eaters)*.</sub>

Yet Voldemort moved back to his old family home when he returned to Britain with Wormtail. Why? His Muggle father caused him nothing but shame, as did his Muggle grandparents. That was why he murdered them. Wouldn't their house have been a place that Voldemort would have wanted to avoid at all costs? Why go back there after all those years?

Comment: Probably because it's the last place he'd expect his enemies to go looking for him

Comment: @Valorum Could also be the first place, especially after the death of Frank Bryce...

Comment: I always thought it was because the Dark Lord needed bone of his father (so anyway had to go to the graveyard) and travelling was not a very comfortable option in the condition he was in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## It was the most logical place to use at the time.

The Dark Lord was in many cases willing to put up with things he’d find distasteful if it suited his larger purpose, like letting Wormtail (who he knew to be a disloyal coward) take care of him and help him brew the potion needed for his resurrection. He surely wasn’t happy about that situation either, but he tolerated it because it was in pursuit of his larger goal. Similarly, he would likely have tolerated staying in his father’s house while preparing for his return to corporeal form. He states himself that the house is a “moderately comfortable” place to stay while their plan (to get Harry to the graveyard to use his blood for the resurrection) was being enacted.

> “There was a pause, and then the man called Wormtail spoke again.
>
> ‘My Lord, may I ask how long we are going to stay here?’
>
> ‘A week,’ said the cold voice. ‘Perhaps longer. The place is moderately comfortable, and the plan cannot proceed yet. It would be foolish to act before the Quidditch World Cup is over.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 1 (The Riddle House)*</sup></sub>

He was willing to stay as long as it suited his plan.

### It was somewhere people avoided - secluded and away from prying eyes.

Ever since the murders of the Riddle family, the Riddle house was abandoned, and except for the boys who sometimes came by to harass the gardener, no one really bothered with it. The only one who was around it was Frank Bryce, who he killed as soon as he knew of his presence.

> “The villagers of Little Hangleton still called it ‘the Riddle House’, even though it had been many years since the Riddle family had lived there. It stood on a hill overlooking the village, some of its windows boarded, tiles missing from its roof, and ivy spreading unchecked over its face. Once a fine-looking manor, and easily the largest and grandest building for miles around, the Riddle House was now damp, derelict and unoccupied.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 1 (The Riddle House)*</sup></sub>

Its owner didn’t use it, so it was somewhere that no one would likely want to reclaim.

> “The wealthy man who owned the Riddle House these days neither lived there nor put it to any use; they said in the village that he kept it for ‘tax reasons’, though nobody was very clear what these might be.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 1 (The Riddle House)*</sup></sub>

As it was abandoned and broken down, as well, it was unlikely to be somewhere people would really want to visit.

### It was near the graveyard where the bones he needed were.

He couldn’t really be transported often, so closer was better, since he was still weak at the time.

> “You will milk her before we retire, Wormtail,’ said the second voice. ‘I will need feeding in the night. The journey has tired me greatly.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 1 (The Riddle House)*</sup></sub>

He did leave, after Moody’s capture, so he could watch Crouch Sr. and control him.

> “And what became of Wormtail after you attacked Moody?’ said Dumbledore.
>
> ‘Wormtail returned to care for my master, in my father’s house, and to keep watch over my father.’
>
> ‘But your father escaped,’ said Dumbledore.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 35 (Veritaserum)*</sup></sub>

He returned to the graveyard to brew the resurrection potion, but it’s unclear how long he’d stayed there before it, after having left the Crouches’ house.

> “My father’s bone, naturally, meant that we would have to come here, where he was buried.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 33 (The Death Eaters)*</sup></sub>

It’s possible he had to dig it up freshly, so that may have necessitated that he brew the resurrection potion in the graveyard. Even if not, it was in a Muggle neighborhood, which was useful to prevent the wizarding world from noticing. The Crouches’ house was likely closer to wizarding society than the Riddle house in Little Hangleton, which was also secluded from the rest of the village.

Answer (score 8):

**He needed access to his father's grave to complete his new body.**

> Bone of the father, unknowingly given, you will renew your son
> Flesh of the servant, willingly sacrificed, you will revive your master
> Blood of the enemy, forcibly taken, you will resurrect your foe

That would have meant that he would need to retrieve the ingredient at some point from the family graveyard in the back of the house.  That the house was nearly abandoned - completely once he killed the old caretaker - would also serve his purposes as a place to hide out and recover.  He was still rather weak, stuck in a cobbled together babyish form, so a place with some creature comforts would appeal.  He seems to have a longing for such things anyway, using the Malfoy's grand manor as a base of operations later.

While Voldemort did hate his father - killed him, in all likelihood - he was practical enough to use the place when it suited him.  Voldemort and Wormtail apparently only stayed there long enough to recover from the trip, and make sure the place was secure, before they moved on Bertha Jorkins information and struck at the Crouch's home to free Crouch Jr.  Presumably they stayed there to keep Crouch in line under Imperius, then returned to the Riddle home to await delivery of their prize once Crouch slipped his leash and ended up dead.

Comment: Wait, was Voldemort in the Riddle house for the whole year? I always thought he stayed there initially when he first arrived and then moved somewhere else. He tells Wormtail he plans to stay there for a week at the start of the book.

Comment: @TheDarkLord - I'm getting forgetful.  edit incoming

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong, by the way. I'm genuinely confused myself. I'm guessing that the house Harry sees in his dream must be the Riddle house (though I never grasped that before). What information do we have to suggest he went to live at the Crouch house?

Comment: Crouch Jr was busy playing the part of Moody, so someone had to be keeping an eye on Crouch Sr.  I doubt they were openly living there, but they'd have to be close at hand to maintain the Imperius

Comment: Wait, I've found confirmation. "Wormtail returned to care for my master, in my father's house, and to keep watch over my father." (Crouch Junior, Veritaserum). So they were in the Crouch house at that time.

Comment: This now makes sense to me. Voldemort went to his family home, presumably because it was the one place he could be sure was vacant. Then he went to live in the Crouch house to control Crouch. When Crouch escaped Voldemort feared that his location was compromised and moved back to the Riddle house.